# Inject in Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am creating a angular 2 application using typescript and need to test the service using Jasmine. As you can see in the test method, I need to inject http to my service for it work. How do I inject HTTP into my service. This is the line of code that i am referring to

var _getCustomerService: GetCustomerService = new GetCustomerService (http);

**Service method**

```
@Injectable()
export class GetCustomerService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    private customerUrl = 'http://localhost:45870/api/getcustomer';

    getCustomer(): Observable<Customer[]> {

        return this.http.get(this.customerUrl)
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server Error'));
    }
}
```

**Jasmine test**

```
describe("Service test", function () {

    it("check service", function () {
         var http: Http;
        var _getCustomerService: GetCustomerService = new GetCustomerService (http);
        _getCustomerService.getCustomer()
            .subscribe(
            (Customer: Customer[]) => {
                var customer: Customer[];
                customer = Customer;
                expect(customer).toBeDefined();
            });


    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to make real XHR requests for the tests, so you will need to create a specialized on for the tests, where you can set mock responses for each request. To do this, you need to use a factory to create your own `Http`, and also make use of the [`MockBackend`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/testing/index/MockBackend-class.html)

```
import { MockBackend, MockConnection } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { Http, HttpMdodule, XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Response, ResponseOptions
       } from '@angular/http';
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';

describe('..', () => {
  let backend: MockBackend;
  let service: GetCustomerService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const injector = TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpModule],
      providers: [
        GetCustomerService,
        RequestOptions,
        MockBackend,
        {
          provide: Http,
          deps: [MockBackend, RequestOptions],
          useFactory: (backend: MockBackend, options: RequestOptions) => {
            return new Http(backend, options);
          }
        }
      ]
    });

    backend = injector.get(MockBackend);
    service = injector.get(GetCustomerService);
  });
});
```

Now in your tests, you want to subscribe to the connections of the `MockBackend` so that you can send a response when a connection comes in

```
it('..', async(() => {
  backend.connections.subscribe((conn: MockConnection) => {
    conn.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({ body: 'some body ' })));
  });

  service.getCustomer().subscribe((Customer: Customer[]) => {
    expect(customer).toBeDefined();
  });
}));
```

**See also:**

- [Testing Services with Http in Angular 2](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/11/28/testing-services-with-http-in-angular-2.html)

Comment: I am getting error at this line of code       useFactory: (backend, options) => {
                        return new Http(backend, options);
                    } . Its says parameter backend implicity has any types. Same message for options

Comment: Whats the error message? See my edit. Maybe you just need to add a type to the parameters

Comment: Its says parameter backend implicity has any types. Same message for options

Comment: Yeah you just need to type it

Comment: I dont understand .Could you explain

Comment: Ooops. I also changed the `XHRBackend` in the `providers` and `deps` to `MockBackend`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130368/discussion-between-tom-and-peeskillet).